# Determine if the following sets of vectors are linearly independent

Tags: linear-algebra

I need to determine if the following set of vectors are are linearly independent or not.

1) $S=\{\mathbf u , \mathbf v , \mathbf w\}\subseteq \mathbb R^3$, it is known that $(1,2,3) \notin \text{span}\{\mathbf u , \mathbf v , \mathbf w\}$

2) $S=\{\mathbf u + \mathbf v,\mathbf u - \mathbf v , \mathbf u - 2\mathbf v +\mathbf w\}\subseteq \mathbb R^n$ where $\{\mathbf u , \mathbf v , \mathbf w\}\subseteq \mathbb R^n$ is a linearly independent set.

3) $S=\{\mathbf u , \mathbf v , \mathbf w\}\subseteq \mathbb R^3$, where it is known that $(1,2,-3),(1,-3,2),(2,-1,5),(0,0,1)$ all belong to $\text{span}\{\mathbf u , \mathbf v , \mathbf w\}$.

I honestly have no idea how to start this, all I know is that the if the vectors $\mathbf u , \mathbf v , \mathbf w$ are linearly independent, then $a\mathbf u + b\mathbf v + c\mathbf w=0$ has only the trivial solution.

Any help here will be appreciated, many thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's another thing you should know about linearly independent vectors: that when you have $n$ vectors in $\mathbb{R}^n$, they span the whole space if and only if they are linearly independent.

Anyway, using only what you told us that you know, it is easy to solve problem 2). Suppose that$$a(\mathbf{u}+\mathbf{v})+b(\mathbf{u}-\mathbf{v})+c(\mathbf{u}-2\mathbf{v}+\mathbf{w})=0.$$This means that$$(a+b+c)\mathbf{u}+(a-b-2c)\mathbf{v}+c\mathbf{w}=0.$$Since your vectors are linearly independent, it follows that $a+b+c=0$, that $a-b-2c=0$ and that $c=0$, from which it is easy to prove that $a=b=c=0$.

Now, in order to solve 1), if $\operatorname{span}\{\mathbf{u},\mathbf{v},\mathbf{w}\}\neq\mathbb{R}^3$, then it follows from my first paragraph that $\mathbf{u}$, $\mathbf{v}$, and $\mathbf{w}$ are *not* linearly independent.

Finally, in order to solve 3), all you need to prove is that$$\operatorname{span}\{ (1,2,−3),(1,−3,2),(2,−1,5),(0,0,1)\}=\mathbb{R}^3.$$Since $ (1,2,−3)$, $(1,−3,2)$, $(2,−1,5)$, and $(0,0,1)$ all belong to $\operatorname{span}\{\mathbf{u},\mathbf{v},\mathbf{w}\}$, you can deduce that $\operatorname{span}\{\mathbf{u},\mathbf{v},\mathbf{w}\}=\mathbb{R}^3$ and that therefore $\mathbf{u}$, $\mathbf{v}$, and $\mathbf{w}$ are linearly independent.

Comment: In 3) should not he first check that in $(1,2,-3),(1,-3,2),(2,-1,5)$ there are 2 linearly independent vectors?

Comment: @gbox I don't see why. What he has to check is that $\langle(1,2,−3),(1,−3,2),(2,−1,5),(0,0,1)\rangle=\mathbb{R}^3$, but there are several ways of doing that.

Comment: I understand better now! Thanks for the help!

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos Theoretically those vectors can be linear combination of $(0,0,1)$ and $(0,1,0)$